# Uniqely identify each device, accessing sencha web applicaiton

Tags: android, iphone, sencha-touch, mac-address, imei

I am developing a sencha based application for iPhone & Android. As a S/W requirement, i need to identify device (on the basis of IMEI or MAC address) accessing the service.
e.g. If a user of iPhone visits my sencha-web-app first time, he will need to register. And if he visits again, Application will detect and registration process will be skipped.

**Q: How can i get IMEI or MAC of device using sencha, to identify it uniquely?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap your Sencha application in a native wrapper. I recommend using PhoneGap, they have a nice UUID property as documented here:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web app running in the browser there is no way to get that information. On iOS, the IMEI is actually restricted information that you can't access anyway.  If you simply want to remember users, the standard way would be to just use a cookie. Is there a particular reason you want to tie this to a hardware identifier and not use a cookie?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am developing an online ordering system for a resturant. I need to identifiy user, visiting site, by his/ her device.